# Controls hide event's of form in C# Windows program

Tags: c#

I had written an event handler for MouseMove for my form
but When I add a panel to form, this handler does NOT run while mouse moves on panel.
I added event handler to panel and this works but I had several panels on the form,
is there an easier solution?

Comment: I have a form with two panels. I want to move some user controls between them (without drag!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could Implement IMessageFilter to pre-process messages that are going to your controls.

http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/10/20/245412.aspx

However, I don't think this is a very clean way to do things from a design perspective.

Comment: It was very useful article, but I was seeking simpler ways ;)

Comment: Thanks OG. I implemented your approach.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, WinForms doesn't support event bubbling. But you can write some code to ease the task of hooking up events.

```
public void AssignMouseMoveEvent(Form form)
{
    foreach(Control control in form.Controls)
    {
        if(! (control is Panel))
            continue;

        control.MouseMove += PanelMouseMove;
    }
}
```

You should call the above code passing it your current form and it will assign PanelMouseMove as event handler for MouseMove event of all the panels.

Comment: Just be aware that e.Location in the PanelMouseMove event handler will be relative to the control that raises the MouseMove event.

Comment: I think that's what the author would need, isn't it?

Comment: Given that the author wants to have the form get all mouse input, I would imagine that it would be preferred if the coordinates were relative to the form, not to the control over which the mouse happens to move. Easy to fix though with a couple of calls to ClientToScreen and ScreenToClient. Just wanted to make the author aware of this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to "propagate" the handlers, so you don't have to re-write the code in each one. Just remember that the MouseMove event has **control-relative coordinates**, so if you pass the event from your panel to your form, you'll have to translate the X & Y values in the event to the form coordinates (something like subtracting panel.location.X from event.X, etc).

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me (assumes you have a form with a panel and a label.  The label is named "MouseCoords"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ShowCoords(int x, int y)
        {
            this.MouseCoords.Text = string.Format("({0}, {1})", x, y);
        }

        private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ShowCoords(e.X, e.Y);
        }

        protected override void OnControlAdded(ControlEventArgs e)
        {
            // hook the mouse move of any control that is added to the form
            base.OnControlAdded(e);
            e.Control.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(Control_MouseMove);
        }

        private void Control_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // convert the mouse coords from control codes to screen coords
            // and then to form coords
            System.Windows.Forms.Control ctrl = (System.Windows.Forms.Control)sender;
            Point pt = this.PointToClient(ctrl.PointToScreen(e.Location));
            this.ShowCoords(pt.X, pt.Y);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.MouseMove += this.Form1_MouseMove;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm familiar with this technique. But what's the effect on performance
when we assign a same handler to many controls.

Comment: Test to check me, but teh performance impact should be minimal -- only 1 control at a time is going to call the event handler.  This does mean that you are instancing a delegate per control.  A delegate is a fancy, type-safe pointer to a function (the "code segment" for the function exists only once -- you are creating references).  Still, if you have tons and tons of controls, you might see some memory impact -- very easy to test though, just comment out the OnControlAdded method, and compare memory usage.

Comment: (oh, 1 quid-pro-quo):  the impact of doing something (anythign) inside of a mousemove itself <b>will</b> likely cause a performance hit.  Mouse move fires very often.  To be more correct with my previous comment, I guess I would say that the cost of multiple controls referencing the same handler should be low, but your overall performance might be impacted by doing a lot of work in the mouse move handler.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no simpler way, and you should assign event handler for each control where you need to receive MouseMove events.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the [`Capture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.capture.aspx) property of the form to true, it will receive all mouse input, regardless of which control that is under the mouse. It will lose the mouse capture at certain operations (I am not sure exactly when, though). Also, according to the documentation for the property, shortcut keys should not work while the mouse is captured.  So, depending on what you want to achieve, this might not be the preferred way to go.

Comment: Capture is reserved for drag operations mostly, because in this case all other controls lose mouse interoperability.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that mouse starts moving over the form rather than over the panel - which is a big assumption - you'll get a MouseLeave event when it enters a sub control. You could check the cursor location and call the mouse move code if it's still within the bounds of the form.

This doesn't work if the mouse move event starts on a control.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution :) "Raise events in controls which hide events"
I catch the event in panel and rise the Mouse move event of the form by calling onMouseMove